# How to ignore NA once converted from a vector to dataframe

Tags: r, na

I cannot find any documentation that supports why `na.rm = true` would ignore `NA` in a vector, but not a dataframe.

See below:

```
df <- c(1,0,1,NA)
mean(df,na.rm = TRUE)
```

Yields: 
`[1] 0.6666667`

But converting `dd` to a dataframe yields an warning and a `NA` for the mean

```
dd <- c(1,1,1,NA)
dd<- as.data.frame(dd)
mean(dd,na.rm = TRUE)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(dd, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

For my problem, I need to ignore NA over a large data frame with 30+ columns - calling each column directly is would be too tedious

Comment: You'd like `mean` for each column or the `mean` of every number in the `data.frame`?

Comment: Ultimately, I would need row-wise means of a data frame that ignored NAs, i.e. df$mean <- *the mean of *df[3:26,]

Comment: Cool, can you give a better example? Like a two-row data.frame with `NA`s, and the resulting data structure you want? It could be a vector of means, or another column of the dataset with the means of the rows, etc.

Comment: Gah! I just got stuck in a meeting - I can put one up on lunch if you want, but tbh, I'm still new-ish to making reproducible examples

Answer (score 1):

By converting to a data frame you created a new data structure in which both the data frame  is "dd" and the column name is "dd". You now need to specify both the data frame and the column:

```
mean(dd$dd, na.rm = TRUE)
with(dd, mean(dd, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: I'm aware that I need to specify the column, but I am looking to calculate the mean across several columns (i.e. df[3:26,]) and need to have na.rm = true to that as well. If an NA appears, I need to ignore it during a row wise mean.

Comment: Something like `rowMeans(df[3:26, ], na.rm=TRUE)` or `apply(df[3:26, ], 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the mean of every number in the data frame, just use `unlist`.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, NA), b = c(3, 4, NA))

mean(unlist(df), na.rm = T)
# [1] 2.5
```

If you want to get the mean of each column.

```
sapply(df, mean, na.rm = T)
#   a   b 
# 1.5 3.5
```

Or, you can do it the `tidyverse` way

```
purrr::map_dbl(df, mean, na.rm = T)
#   a   b 
# 1.5 3.5
```